# WCF Setup: How to access a WCF from multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a solution that we provide to each of our customers.

eg:

```
customer1.ourCompany.com  
customer2.ourCompany.com
```

Each customer has a WCF integration to one of our partners.
Eg:

```
customer1.ourPartner.com  
customer2.ourPartner.com
```

#### QUESTION 1:

Now I'm trying to have our solution setup in a way, where I only have 1 connected service in my solution, instead of my whole solution has to have a connection to ALL ourPartner WCFs.

In my head this sound very simple.
The contract is the same for all endpoints, so I thought that I could just change to endpoint on deployment. and that would be it.

However each service is deployed to its own server, so each service is called something else, and I can't figure out how to "just instantiate a GenericPartnerService() proxy"
where the config file just need to be modified to each constumer alike this:

```
</system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOurPartnerService">
      <security mode="Transport" />
     </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <client>
  <endpoint address="https://ws.ourPartner.dk/services/Service11066.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"   
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IOurPartnerService"                  
            contract="GenericCustomer.IGenericService"   
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IOurPartnerService" />
 </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

#### QUESTION 2:

The autogenerated proxy has 100+ of methods and we only need to use 6 of them.
What is a clever way to create a partial proxy, that only exposes those 6 methods?

I am aware that I should be able to use a HTTPClient(), and call the 6 methods/endpoints individually, but somehow that doesn't seem to compute (I get hhtp response code 400)

Shouldn't I be able to just implement my own contract interface, if I know what the contract looks like ?

Comment: This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/multiple-endpoints) shows server and client configurations with multiple endpoints, using different bindings. In addition, is there any detailed error information in question 2?